# Sort: Get the author's documents before other documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have the following question: 
Is there any way to use a specific constant value as a tie-breaker when sorting?

Here's my example:

Assume the index structure:

```
{
     title: "Title",
     author: "Name of author"
}
```

Say we have the following search query : http://example.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=test&return=_all_fields%2C_score&sort=_score%20desc

The problem is I have if there are 10 documents with the same title "test" they will all have the same score, now I want to sort these documents and get the documents created by the current author on top. I have tried using an expression but I can't seem to get it to work, this is what I tried:

http://example.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=test&return=_all_fields%2C_score&sort=_score%20desc,isauthor%20desc&expr.isauthor=(author%3D%3D%id) however I doubt that cloudsearch will accept that. Is there any way to solve this via the search string or do I need to index something like a numeric author identifier?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is interested, this is what I ended up doing.

Created a new index field : `author_identifier` which I used to index a unique integer identifier for each user (which was another challenge to get because the user ids were GUIDs so I had to associate them with numbers.

Then I used a sort expression: http://example.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=test&return=_all_fields%2C_score&sort=_score%20desc,isauthor%20desc&expr.isauthor=(author_identifer%3D%3D%mappedid)

This was not an ideal solution, but it's better than nothing I guess.